# Remove string between 2 pattern using gawk regex only

Tags: regex, awk

## Input:

```
secNm:ATA,_class:com.dddao.domaffin.summaggrfy.GddenericMohsg},{ttlRec:0,ttlVal:{:0}secNm:B2B,_class:com.xyz.dakjdain.sfffummary.GenericMo73hs}extra
```

secNm:ATA,_class:com.dddao.domaffin.summaggrfy.GddenericMohsg},{ttlRec:0,ttlVal:{:0}secNm:B2B,_class:com.xyz.dakjdain.sfffummary.GenericMo73hs

In above both the string I want to remove,
For String 1: parts which stars from ",_class" and ends at 1st occurrence "}"
For String 2: parts which stars from ",_class" till the end if if 1st condition fails.

## Output:

`secNm:ATA,{ttlRec:0,ttlVal:{:0}secNm:B2Bextra`
`secNm:ATA,{ttlRec:0,ttlVal:{:0}secNm:B2B`

This type of pattern is present undefinable times in this above string.
I want simple want to remove those part.

I have written regex function `gsub(/,_class(.*?)\}/,"",$0)`

I want answer only using gawk regex function only no other method.
My above give function is having some issue and removing big part of the string.
Help me to correct my regex formula please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks a lot its working..

Comment: Strange but one more help in same case,
ttlCess:0,chkSum:74313561d1897af3dc03f4fae174960d28968f92b49230523faca462b848db60,secNm:CDNUR

In above line I want to remove it from ",chkSum" till 1st ","
I just edit your regex and tried to apply on this but it dint work..
gsub(/,chkSum[^,]*}/,"}",$0)

Can you tell me what the issue in this.
Sorry for trouble.

Comment: If you need to remove up to the first `,`, use `gsub(/,chkSum[^,]*,/,",",$0)`

Comment: BTW, if you want to keep `,` or `}`, you do not even need to put them to the end of the pattern and then you won't have to replace with those chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a `[^}]` negated bracket expression to match any char but `}` since lazy quantifiers are not supported.

Besides, you do not even need a grouping construct here as you are not referring to the captured value here. You may remove `(` and `)` safely.

Use

```
/,_class[^}]*}/
```

Basically, this should be understood as:

- `,_class` - match `,_class` substring
- `[^}]*` - 0 or more chars other than `}`
- `}` - up to  and including `}`.